# What's the measure of the segment $BN$ in tre triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Angle $B$ of an acute triangle ABC measures $60^o$.In its interior is located the point
P such that PA + PB + PC is the minimum; let $I$, and $l_2$, are the incenters of the triangles $ABP$ and $BPC$ repectively. Through $I$, e $I_2$ we trace parallels to $BP$ which intersect at $M$ and $N$ to $AB$ and $BC$ respectively; if $BM =a$. Find $BN$ (Answer:$a$.)

My progress:
[image]

Corrected drawing with the auxiliary instruction to generate Fermat's point as per article provided by ACB

$\triangle CJN \sim \triangle CPB \implies\frac{CN}{BC} = \frac{CJ}{CP}=\frac{JN}{BM}\\
\triangle AMH \sim \triangle ABP \implies\frac{AM}{AB} = \frac{AH}{AP}=\frac{MH}{BP}$

Th. Thales:$\frac{CN}{BN} = \frac{CJ}{JP}  \implies BN = \frac{CN.JP}{CJ}$

I don't know if there is a property that gives the sum of the smallest distance from an interior point of a triangle to the vertices

Comment: See [Fermat point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point).

Comment: BN is equal to BM

Comment: @peta_arantes. Can you post the name of the textbook wherefrom are you taking all your geometry problems?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  Sure..."Problemas De Geometría Y Cómo Resolverlos - Racso"

Comment: @ACB  Very good...I didn't know that theorem...the solution must be out there....

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  you are right...the segments will be equal...can you demonstrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

$I$ and $J$ are incenters of $\triangle APB$ and $\triangle BPC$ respectively.

As $MI$ is parallel to $BP$ and $I$ is incenter,

$\displaystyle \frac{BM}{MX} = \frac{PI}{IX} = \frac{BP}{BX}$

and similarly, $ ~ \displaystyle \frac{BN}{NY} = \frac{PJ}{JY} = \frac{BP}{BY}$

So if we can show that $BX = BY$, that would show $BM = BN$ and we are done.

By some angle chasing, we can show that $\triangle PBX \sim \triangle PCY$ and I leave this as an exercise for you.

Then, $ \displaystyle \frac{BX}{BP} = \frac{CY}{CP}$

But given $PY$ is angle bisector of $\angle BPC$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{CY}{CP} = \frac{BY}{BP}$

$ \therefore BX = BY ~ $ and that completes the proof that $BM = BN$.

Comment: Excellent as always...I was able to understand everything and demonstrate the indicated similarity. Thnak very nuch.

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome!